# Type Mismatch in Split Function

Tags: vba, types, split, mismatch

my code snippet is quite short & simple but I am still not able to get it to work.

```
Dim feld As Variant
Dim Num As Variant
Dim strNum As String
Dim Bank As String

Bank = IIf(DKB.Value = True, "DKB", IIf(DB.Value = True, "DB", IIf(Kasse.Value = True, "Kasse", "BfS")))

strNum = Sheets(Bank).Range("B11").Value
feld = Split(strNum, "_")
```

The value of strNum is "202_DKB_02".

If I try to run it, I get a Type Mismatch Error in the last step. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `strNum = "202_DKB_02"`? Because with that value it's not giving me any error.

Comment: Replace `Split` with `VBA.Strings.Split` and if it works, it means you have local Sub/Function with the same name expecting different parameters.

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. Thanks a lot! I should overthink my naming convention now..